# PHP Routing - Error include css/js files

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I am learning to do routing in php. I am able to route the page without any error but I am stuck on including the `css` and `js` files. The medium that I use for the tutorial and example is on *laracast* video. I am also using `xampp` for the apache server on Windows.

I wanted to make my own practice and below image are the file structure that I did,

- [File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dCKi.jpg)

on my `.htaccess` file, I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /season-temp
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [END]
```

On my views folder, I have all the view page file including `header` and `footer` to include the `css` and `js`.

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Logo Nav - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/logo-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<?php require('navigations.php'); ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

From the codes above, it will give an error:

```
GET http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css 
GET http://localhost/css/logo-nav.css 
GET http://localhost/js/jquery.js 
GET http://localhost/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

I tried to insert `<base href="/">` on the head section and make the link on each src/href like `'season-temp/<folder_name>/<file_name>'`, eg; `'season-temp/css/bootstrap.min.css'`  but still unable to get the css and js files.

How do I want to include those files?

> **Update - Incorrect output**

Firstly, apologize for the wrong update on below solution. The css and js did work but the link is broken. If I undo the `.htaccess` file base on @Triby answer, the link works fine but the css and js is not. Below are the page for my `navigations.php` and `routes.php`

**navigations.php**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
         <a href="/season-temp/about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/season-temp/services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/season-temp/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

$router->get('season-temp','controllers/index.php');

$router->get('season-temp/about','controllers/about.php');

$router->get('season-temp/services','controllers/services.php');

$router->get('season-temp/contact','controllers/contact.php');
```

If I update the link as @ceejayoz mentioned for the css and js files, I got an error of:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 
'No route defined for this URI.' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\season-temp\core\router.php:30
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\season-temp\index.php(9): 
Router-&gt;direct('season-temp/js/...', 'GET')
#1 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\season-temp\core\router.php</b> 
on line <b>30</b><br />
```

Comment: That's not an error. What's the actual error? Is the URL `http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css ` accessible?

Comment: @ceejayoz seems they do, check the image provided

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry for not pointing it right. If I copy and paste the url `http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css`. It's unable to retrieve the page with `error 404`

Comment: @brianforan The `RewriteBase /season-temp` makes me think they're in a sub-folder, which means that URL won't be accessible.

Comment: @Khairul Are you accessing your site via `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/season-temp`?

Comment: @ceejayoz the css folder should be in `localhost/season-temp/css/...`

Comment: @ceejayoz I am accessing using http://localhost/season-temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am accessing using `http://localhost/season-temp/`

This is the problem.

Your files are all referenced like this:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

but you should be using:

```
<script src="/season-temp/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already tried insert like you suggest but still unable to make it right. The solution is from @Triby answer. Besides the `.htaccess` file, I also need to remove the 'foward slash' `/` on each links. For eg, `/js/jquery.js` will be `js/jquery.js`

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting everything to index.php, try to redirect only inexistent files or directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /season-temp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

L is to avoid processing any rules below when the rule matches

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally got it to work. Do you have a reference on the Rewrite part. Still confuse on that or could you briefly explain the condition =)

Comment: %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is the requested file or directory by URL, !-f is to apply the rule if file doesn't exist, !-d if directory doesn't exist.

Comment: That means if the _file_ or _directory_ does not exist, then, execute the rule below. That is to point to `index.php`. Am I right?